# Fastest modern C++ way to generate a 1GB file with arbitrary binary data

Tags: c++, performance, file-io

So, I've tried this:

```
uint64_t size = 1 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000;
std::vector<char> data(size, 'a');

std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("test.dat");
for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
{
    myfile << *it;
}

myfile.close();
```

Which works but takes > 15 minutes in release. I'm running with a 1TB NVME ssd and 64GBs of RAM, I feel like I should be able to do this in seconds, **or less than a second.**

I do have access to C++20. I prefer something modern for its readability so long as its reasonably performant. I feel like anything over 10 seconds is too slow.

To be clear, pushing back into the array all of the data is nearly instant. But writing it is what's taking minutes.

Comment: Why don't `std::vector<char> data(size, '\ba')`, it saves 5 lines of the code.

Comment: Heh yeah good call, will do :) I didn't spend too much time on this code since it was just an example.

Comment: `myfile << data.data();` doesn't do what you think. Look at the file size and content. The worst case, it results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, was a typo. changed it to insert *it. I tried to put the whole buffer in in earlier code but like you said, it doesn't work that way

Comment: @JoshSanders: What's the point of pre-initializing the buffer, then adding `size` *more* elements to it?

Comment: Before I was simply reserving, so I wasn't adding any more elements to it. Forgot to remove that loop from here.

Comment: Don't bother doing "modern C++" for such a thing, just `mmap` it and let the OS do its magic.

Answer (score 5):

Writing one byte at a time leads to a high overhead, *especially* if the file is unbuffered and you're making a system call for each byte. Likewise, `operator<<` writes *formatted* data, which does the right thing for a char but is more error-prone, since many inputs will get formatted during writing.

Instead, you already have access to a buffer full of `char` - the simplest solution is to just write the whole buffer with `ofstream::write`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    uint64_t size = 2 * 1000 *1000 * 1000;
    std::vector<char> data;
    data.reserve(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        data.push_back('a');
    }

    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("test.dat");
    myfile.write(data.data(), size);

    myfile.close();
}
```

When straced, the example above only uses one syscall to write:

```
writev(3, [{iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}, {iov_base="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"..., iov_len=2000000000}], 2) = 2000000000
```

Better yet, write (e.g.) a 1 MB block 1000 times, to avoid allocating a whole gigabyte of RAM:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    uint64_t size = 1000 * 1000;
    std::vector<char> data;
    data.reserve(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        data.push_back('a');
    }

    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("test.dat");
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        myfile.write(data.data(), size);
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

Finally, pay attention to what you're putting into the buffer. `\ba` is is a multibyte character - `\b` is an escape for `0x08` and `a` is `a`. On my machine, this gets truncated to just `a`. If you want more interesting data in your file, instead change the loop that fills the buffer.

Comment: Ahh nice... "If you want more interesting data in your file, instead change the loop that fills the buffer." Okay so I could just have an array of hex values and pick a random index each time, yeah? Just like `unsigned char values[17] = "abcdef0123456789";` ?

Comment: @JoshSanders Or any other algorithm that puts data into the buffer following a rule you're interested in. I don't know what arbitrary data you want, and your intent wasn't clear based on `'\ba'` which was just turning to `'a'` after narrowing.

Comment: Okay. Yeah for my purposes it really doesn't matter, just needs to be something. when is `\b` used then? I was wrongly under the impression that it was needed. Something about nibbles but clearly I was incorrect

Comment: @JoshSanders A char variable holds one character. `\b` *is* a character, specifically 0x08. You just happened to try to pack two characters into a single `char`, which doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: @JoshSanders *"when is `\b` used then? I was wrongly under the impression that it was needed."* -- maybe you're thinking of `\xba`, where `ba` is the character code in hexadecimal (186 in decimal)? When giving the code in hexadecimal, each digit corresponds to a nibble.

Comment: Ahh yeah that must've been it

Answer (score 2):

Don't make a 2GB array in memory.

Take a chunk size, something like 65536 bytes.  The exact optimal size depends on your OS and filesystem.

Fill a buffer of that chunk size and write it with iostream::write.

Something like this:

```
const size_t sz = 65536;
uint8_t data[sz];
for ( /* blah */) {
    fill_random_data(data, sz);
    outfile.write(data, sz);
}
```